# Python 3.5 async for blocks the ioloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a simple aiohttp-server with two handlers.
First one does some computations in the `async for` loop. Second one just returns text response. `not_so_long_operation` returns 30-th fibonacci number with the slowest recursive implementation, which takes something about one second.

```
def not_so_long_operation():
    return fib(30)

class arange:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0

    async def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        i = self.i
        self.i += 1
        if self.i <= self.n:
            return i
        else:
            raise StopAsyncIteration

# GET /
async def index(request):
    print('request!')
    l = []
    async for i in arange(20):
        print(i)
        l.append(not_so_long_operation())

    return aiohttp.web.Response(text='%d\n' % l[0])

# GET /lol/
async def lol(request):
    print('request!')
    return aiohttp.web.Response(text='just respond\n')
```

When I'm trying to fetch `/` and then `/lol/`, it gives me response for the second one only when the first one gets finished.
What am I doing wrong and how to make index handler release the ioloop on each iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example has no *yield points* (`await` statements) for switching between tasks.
Asynchronous iterator **allows** to use `await` inside `__aiter__`/`__anext__` but don't insert it automatically into your code.

Say,

```
class arange:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0

    async def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        i = self.i
        self.i += 1
        if self.i <= self.n:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  # insert yield point
            return i
        else:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
```

should work as you expected.

In real application most likely you don't need `await asyncio.sleep(0)` calls because you will wait on database access and similar activities.

Comment: So, as far as I understood, according to [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#why-stopasynciteration), `async for` was added to avoid collisions with `StopIteration`, used in coroutines internally?

Comment: Not exactly.
`async for` uses `__aiter__`/`__anext__` pair of coroutines.
Let's assume we read bulk of data from DB (like [redis iscan command](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis/blob/master/aioredis/commands/generic.py#L210-L220) ).
It fetches a bulk of data, returns it item by item and fetch next bulk on data  exhausting. You may perform I/O in `__aiter__` coroutine with help of `await` statement but cannot do it in old-good `__iter__` method.

Answer (score 3):

Since, `fib(30)` is CPU bound and sharing little data, you should probably use a [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) (as opposed to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`):

```
async def index(request):
    loop = request.app.loop
    executor = request.app["executor"]
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, fib, 30)
    return web.Response(text="%d" % result)
```

Setup `executor` when you create the `app`:

```
app = Application(...)
app["exector"] = ProcessPoolExector()
```

Comment: `fib(30)` is just an example of operation, which runs not so long once, but long enough while running in the loop. CPU-bound operation was not the best idea, but thank you for your snippet!

Answer (score 2):

An asynchronous iterator is not really needed here. Instead you can simply give the control back to the event loop inside your loop. In python 3.4, this is done by using a simple `yield`:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def index(self):
    for i in range(20):
        not_so_long_operation()
        yield
```

In python 3.5, you can define an `Empty` object that basically does the same thing:

```
class Empty:
    def __await__(self):
        yield
```

Then use it with the `await` syntax:

```
async def index(request):
    for i in range(20):
        not_so_long_operation()
        await Empty()
```

Or simply use [asyncio.sleep(0)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) that has been [recently optimized](https://github.com/python/asyncio/commit/f11cc8f1ed12ffaca656ddae35594425c0a86145):

```
async def index(request):
    for i in range(20):
        not_so_long_operation()
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

You could also run the `not_so_long_operation` in a thread using the [default executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executor):

```
async def index(request, loop):
    for i in range(20):
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, not_so_long_operation)
```

Comment: is it necessary to construct Empty object each time?
Is it ok to create `next_tick = Empty()` and then use it with `await next_tick`?

Comment: @MichaelIhnatenko Sure it's fine, though I'm surprised there's no standard way to give the control back to the event loop in python 3.5.