# Lazy iterators (generators) with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a blocking, non-async code like this:

```py
def f():
    def inner():
        while True:
            yield read()
    return inner()
```

With this code the caller can choose when to stop the function to generate data. How to change this to async? This solution doesn't work:

```py
async def f():
    async def inner():
        while True:
            yield await coroutine_read()
    return inner()
```

... because  `yield` can't be used in `async def` functions. If i remove the `async` from the `inner()` signature, I can't use `await` anymore.

Comment: You don't need `yield read()` when using asyncio, because `await` will do exactly this behind the scenes. This doesn't answer the question of course.

Comment: PEP-0492 [doesn't cover](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#coroutine-generators) coroutine-generators (which is what you want), so, since the PEP was only implemented in 3.5, I guess the answer is "there's no way to do this".

Comment: Attempt to implement way to yield inside async functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37572657/1113207

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 'yield' inside async function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549846/how-to-use-yield-inside-async-function)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Upd:**

Starting with Python 3.6 we have [asynchronous generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) and able to use `yield` directly inside coroutines.

---

As noted above, you can't use `yield` inside `async` funcs. If you want to create [coroutine-generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#coroutine-generators) you have to do it manually, using `__aiter__` and `__anext__` magic methods:

```
import asyncio


# `coroutine_read()` generates some data:
i = 0
async def coroutine_read():
    global i
    i += 1
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    return i


# `f()` is asynchronous iterator.
# Since we don't raise `StopAsyncIteration` 
# it works "like" `while True`, until we manually break.
class f:
    async def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        return await coroutine_read()


# Use f() as asynchronous iterator with `async for`:
async def main():
    async for i in f():
        print(i)
        if i >= 3:
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
[Finished in 6.2s]
```

You may also like to see [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36094436/1113207), where `StopAsyncIteration` uses.

Comment: You should note that this approach is incorrect in Py 3.7 and later versions.