# Is there any faster way for downloading multiple files from s3 to local folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, boto3

I am trying to download 12,000 files from s3 bucket using jupyter notebook, which is estimating to complete download in 21 hours. This is because each file is downloaded one at a time. Can we do multiple downloads parallel to each other so I can speed up the process?

Currently, I am using the following code to download all files

```
### Get unique full-resolution image basenames
images = df['full_resolution_image_basename'].unique()
print(f'No. of unique full-resolution images: {len(images)}')

### Create a folder for full-resolution images
images_dir = './images/'
os.makedirs(images_dir, exist_ok=True)

### Download images
images_str = "','".join(images)
limiting_clause = f"CONTAINS(ARRAY['{images_str}'], 
full_resolution_image_basename)"
_ = download_full_resolution_images(images_dir, 
limiting_clause=limiting_clause)
```

Comment: Can you call out to the OS and call the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? It has an `aws s3 cp` command that can copy files in parallel. Also useful is `aws s3 sync`, which is good for recovering from failed copies.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See the code below. This  will only work with python 3.6+, because of the f-string ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498)). Use a different method of string formatting for older versions of python.

Provide the `relative_path`, `bucket_name` and `s3_object_keys`. In addition, [max_workers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)  is optional, and if not provided the number will be a multiple of 5 times the  number of machine processors.

Most of the code for this answer came from an answer to [How to create an async generator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359350)
 which sources from this example [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) in the library.

```
import boto3
import os
from concurrent import futures


relative_path = './images'
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
s3_object_keys = [] # List of S3 object keys
max_workers = 5

abs_path = os.path.abspath(relative_path)
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def fetch(key):
    file = f'{abs_path}/{key}'
    os.makedirs(file, exist_ok=True)  
    with open(file, 'wb') as data:
        s3.download_fileobj(bucket_name, key, data)
    return file


def fetch_all(keys):

    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future_to_key = {executor.submit(fetch, key): key for key in keys}

        print("All URLs submitted.")

        for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_key):

            key = future_to_key[future]
            exception = future.exception()

            if not exception:
                yield key, future.result()
            else:
                yield key, exception


for key, result in fetch_all(S3_OBJECT_KEYS):
    print(f'key: {key}  result: {result}')
```

Comment: `fetch` should create a new session as per: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-multiprocessing

Comment: I agree, but I don't think that is the case with the `client` interface, so I adjusted the answer to use the `client` interface, which `resource` interface just wraps around. I try to avoid creating `sessions`, `clients`, and `resources`, because those actions are costly.

Comment: I ended up using a `threading.local()` to cache the session so it was reused by the jobs in the executor.

Comment: @DamonMaria Can you explain where you included this?

Comment: @Austin I can't find where I used that code now. Do you mean where the `session` or the `local` was included?

Comment: @DamonMaria the local

Comment: Create a `local` object at your module top level: `cache = threading.local()`. Then create the session if need be before using it: `if not hasattr(cache 'session'): cache.session = <create new session>`

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for this. Had 9000 over JPEG images that I needed to download from my S3. I tried to incorporate this directly into my Colab Pro but wasn't able to get it to work. Kept getting "Errno 21 : Is a directory" error.

Had to add 2 things: 1) a makedir to create the directory I want & 2) use mknod, instead of mkdir.

fetch_all is almost the same: except a small edit for max_workers to actually take effect. s3c is just my boto3.client with my keys and all.

My download time went from 30+ mins to 5 mins with 1000 workers.

```
os.makedirs('/*some dir you want*/*prefix*')

def fetch(key):
    file = f'{abs_path}/{key}'
    os.mknod(file, mode=384)  
    with open(file, 'wb') as data:
        s3c.download_fileobj(bucket_name, key, data)
    return file

def fetch_all(keys):

    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        future_to_key = {executor.submit(fetch, key): key for key in keys}

        print("All URLs submitted.")

        for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_key):

            key = future_to_key[future]
            exception = future.exception()

            if not exception:
                yield key, future.result()
            else:
                yield key, exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. This is fast

```
import boto3
from multiprocessing import Pool

bucket_name = 'BUCKET_NAME'
prefix = 'PREFIX'
local_dir = './downloads/' # PUT YOUR LOCAL DIR 
max_process = 20 # CAN BE CHANGE
debug_en = True

# pass your credentials and region name
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=' ',
                     aws_secret_access_key=' ', region_name=' ')


def downfiles(bucket_name, src_obj, dest_path):

    try:
        s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, src_obj, dest_path)
        if debug_en:
            print("[dubug] downloading object: %s to %s" %(src_obj, dest_path))
    except:
        pass


def download_dir(bucket_name, sub_prefix):
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=sub_prefix)
    pool = Pool(max_process)
    print(pool)
    mp_data = []
    for page in pages:
        if 'Contents' in page:
            for obj in page['Contents']:
                src_obj = obj['Key']
                dest_path = local_dir + src_obj
                mp_data.append((bucket_name, src_obj, dest_path))
                os.path.dirname(dest_path) and os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_path), exist_ok=True) 
    pool.starmap(downfiles, mp_data)
    return len(mp_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("starting script...")
    start_time = datetime.now()
    s3_dirs = prefix
    total_files = 0
    for s3_dir in s3_dirs:
        print("[Information] %s directory is downloading" % s3_dir)
        no_files = download_dir(bucket_name, s3_dir)
        total_files = total_files + no_files

    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print('Total File numbers: %d' % total_files)
    print("ended")
```

Comment: how fast is this relative to other answers?