# How can I use motor's open_download_stream work with FastAPI's StreamingResponse?

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, mongodb-motor

I'm building a FastAPI endpoint where web client user can essentially download files which are stored in MongoDB as GridFS chunks.  However, FastAPI's [StreamingResponse](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse) doesn't take the supposedly file-like [AsyncIOMotorGridOut](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_gridfs.html?highlight=upload_file#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorGridOut) object returned by motor's [open_download_stream](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_gridfs.html?highlight=upload_file#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket) method.

I already have an endpoint which can take files in a form and cause them to be uploaded to MongoDB.  I would expect a similar download helper function to be as simple as this:

```
async def upload_file(db, file: UploadFile):
    """ Uploads file to MongoDB GridFS file system and returns ID to be stored with collection document """
    fs = AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket(db)
    file_id = await fs.upload_from_stream(
        file.filename,
        file.file,
        # chunk_size_bytes=255*1024*1024, #default 255kB
        metadata={"contentType": file.content_type})
    return file_id
```

My first attempt is to use a helper like this:

```
async def download_file(db, file_id):
    """Returns  AsyncIOMotorGridOut (non-iterable file-like object)"""
    fs = AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket(db)
    stream = await fs.open_download_stream(file_id)
    # return download_streamer(stream)
    return stream
```

My FastAPI endpoint looks like this:

```
app.get("/file/{file_id}")
async def get_file(file_id):
    file = await download_file(db, file_id)
    return StreamingResponse(file, media_type=file.content_type)
```

When trying to download a file with a valid `file_id`, I get this error: `TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorGridOut' object is not an iterator`

My 2nd attempt has been to make a generator to iterate over chunks of the file:

```
async def download_streamer(file: AsyncIOMotorGridOut):
    """ Returns generator file-like object to be served by StreamingResponse
    https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse
    """
    chunk_size = 255*1024*1024
    for chunk in await file.readchunk():
        print(f"chunk: {chunk}")
        yield chunk
```

I then use the commented `return download_streamer(stream)` in my `download_file` helper, but for some reason, every chunk is just an integer of `255`.

What's the best way to get a file out of MongoDB using motor and streaming it as a FastAPI web response without using a temporary file?  (I don't have access to hard drive, and I don't want to store the whole file in memory - I just want to stream files from MongoDB through FastAPI directly to client a chunk at a time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to create a generator which happens to be in Python 3.6+ syntax per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37550568/682515).  Such an iterator works with the async variant of FastAPI's StreamingResponse, and reads one GridFS chunk at a time ([defaults to 255KB per motor docs](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_gridfs.html?highlight=upload_file#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket)) using [`readchunk()`](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_gridfs.html?highlight=upload_file#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorGridOut.readchunk) method.  This chunk size is set when file is stored in MongoDB using `upload_from_stream()`.  An optional implementation would be to use `.read(n)` to read `n` bytes at a time.  I chose to use `readchunk()` so exactly 1 DB document is being fetched at a time during the stream (each GridFS file is broken up into chunks and stored one chunk at a time in the DB)

```
async def chunk_generator(grid_out):
    while True:
        # chunk = await grid_out.read(1024)
        chunk = await grid_out.readchunk()
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk


async def download_file(db, file_id):
    """Returns iterator over AsyncIOMotorGridOut object"""
    fs = AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket(db)
    grid_out = await fs.open_download_stream(file_id)
    return chunk_generator(grid_out)
```

A future improvement will be to have `download_file()` return a tuple so as to include not only the generator, but metadata like `ContentType`.