GridFS saving file info to files collection, but not saving any chunks?
I have this very basic GridFS util for usage between GridFS and FastAPI
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket
from fastapi import UploadFile
from bson import ObjectId
from bson.errors import InvalidId
from pymongo.errors import PyMongoError


async def ChunkGenerator(
    grid_out,
):  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65866200/how-can-i-use-motors-open-download-stream-work-with-fastapis-streamingresponse
    while True:
        chunk = await grid_out.readchunk()
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk


async def GetFile(evidence_id: str, db):
    try:
        fs = AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket(db)
        file = await fs.open_download_stream(ObjectId(evidence_id))
        content_type = file.metadata.get("content_type", "application/octet-stream")
        return ChunkGenerator(file), content_type
    except (InvalidId, FileNotFoundError, PyMongoError):
        return None


async def StoreFile(file: UploadFile, db, uploader: int = "Unknown"):
    try:
        fs = AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket(db)
        file_id = await fs.upload_from_stream(
            file.filename,
            file.file,
            metadata={"uploader": str(uploader), "content_type": file.content_type},
        )
        return str(file_id)
    except PyMongoError:
        return None


async def DeleteFile(evidence_id: str, db):
    try:
        fs = AsyncIOMotorGridFSBucket(db)
        await fs.delete(ObjectId(evidence_id))
        return True
    except (InvalidId, FileNotFoundError, PyMongoError):
        return False

I noticed that GetFile, when used properly, returns a ChunkGenerator with seemingly no data. I decided to investigate my actual mongodb database, and found that the file info was stored successfully, but no chunks were stored at all.


Worth noting the db arg is a pymongo motor client.
Thank you!

Test with some generic content like b"data I want to store!" instead of file.file - if that string winds up in the database the problem is with the file or how it is being presented to upload function, if it is not the problem is with motor or the database.

@Joe Hey! Thanks for the reply. I tried inputting a bytestring and it certainly seemed to work a lot better. https://i.imgur.com/mjqvNAU.png Only question now is how I can go about making it work with files!

Got it working, thank you so much for the help. My solution was instead of passing the UploadFile object as an argument, I only passed the contents bytes and put it in a BytesIO stream
