# Wrap blocking Python function in asyncio with stdout presented as async generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, stdout

I want to wrap a blocking function in Python 3.7+ so that it runs async while handling whatever output it produces on stdout asynchronously by a handler (in my case sending them over the network). This assumes that the blocking function in effect a black box that cannot be changed.

I believe the parts of what I want to do has been presented well already, but combining them has turned out to be a challenge for me:

1. I want to wrap a blocking function in asyncio (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063331/how-to-use-asyncio-with-existing-blocking-library)).
2. I want whatever is output as stdout by that blocking function to be captured (explained [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/))
3. I want the captured stdout lines to be presented as an async Python generator (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549846/how-to-use-yield-inside-async-function)).

My current code looks like this:

```
def run_in_executor(f):
    """
    Decorator to run things in an async executor
    """
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: f(*args, **kwargs))

    return inner


@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(stream):
    """
    Context to capture stdout in given stream
    """
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = stream
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout

def dummy_blocking_task():
    sec=10
    ct=sec
    print(f"Doing blocking task for {sec} seconds")
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(f"dummy stdout {ct}")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        ct -= 1
        if ct<=0:
            break
    print(f"Blocking task finished after {sec} seconds")


# Wrap in async
@run_in_executor
def async_build():
    # Create a in memory text based stream
    stream = io.StringIO()
    # POI: How can I asyncrounously handle the captured stdio lines as they are put into stream?
    def some_magic_handler(line):
        send_somewhere(f"HANDLED STDIO LINE: {line}")
    some_magic_way(stream, some_magic_handler)
    # Redirect stdout to the stream
    with redirect_stdout(stream):
        # Run the blocking function
        res = dummy_blocking_task()
    
    return ret
```

So how would I repace my pseudo functions `some_magic_handler` and `some_magic_way` for this to work?

Comment: I don't really understand why this has been downwoted. Does Stack Overflow have a bot problem?