# How to use await inside map function

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have the following code

```py
async def foo():
   some_tuple = tuple(map(bar, some_tuple))
```

```py
async def bar(data):
   # Await another function and do some other stuff
   return something
```

Since `bar` is async it must be awaited. However, I am unsure where to await `bar`. I tried awaiting it inside `map`, I tried awaiting `map`, I tried awaiting `tuple` and nothing worked.

How do I await `bar` inside `map`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093838/how-can-i-asynchronously-map-filter-an-asynchronous-iterable/39125333

Comment: @Belegnar The question is related to, but not really a duplicate of the one you pointed. In the older question the poster was aware how to write an async version of `map`, but was faced with the lack of async generator in then's Python. The answers concentrated on (now obsolete) ways to implement the async iterator without an async generator, which is not what the OP here needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `map` with async functions since map is synchronous and doesn't suspend execution inside the loop. The same applies to the `tuple` constructor which expects a synchronous generator.

Ti fix this, you can replace the `map`/`tuple` pair with a list comprehension, which can be async, and readily converted to tuple:

```
some_tuple = tuple([await fn(elem) for elem in iterable])
```

Another option is to use the async versions of `map` and `tuple` from the [asyncstdlib](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, which also provides a lot of additional and useful functionality:

```
import asyncstdlib.builtins.map as amap
import asyncstdlib.builtins.tuple as atuple

some_tuple = await atuple(amap(fn, iterable))
```

Comment: I tried all 3 methods, I get `TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable` for each of them. Sorry, I am new to async in Python.

Comment: @SarmaEater Yeah, the problem is that `tuple` is non-async as well. I've now amended the answer.